# VARSelection - Results points to 1 or 10? What criteria follow?

Tags: r, aic, vector-autoregression, lags

I have found this values with VARS::VARSelect() in R.

but i can't definie with my results what is the best lag order. 
My data (exog and endog are all stationary with 1 differentiating)

**All data follows as "Y"**

```
str(Y)
 Time-Series [1:85] from 1996 to 2017: 773829 781874 803765 829058 814855 ...
```

Here the VARselect

```
endogenas = window(ts.intersect(Y, C), freq=4)
exogenas = window(ts.intersect(FBK, G, Xl), freq=4)   
Varlag = VARselect(endogenas, exogen = exogenas, lag.max = 10)


> Varlag
$selection
AIC(n)  HQ(n)  SC(n) FPE(n) 
    10      1      1     10 

$criteria
                  1            2            3            4            5            6
AIC(n) 3.717945e+01 3.718569e+01 3.720576e+01 3.727125e+01 3.730199e+01 3.728798e+01
HQ(n)  3.732751e+01 3.738310e+01 3.745252e+01 3.756736e+01 3.764746e+01 3.768280e+01
SC(n)  3.755025e+01 3.768009e+01 3.782375e+01 3.801284e+01 3.816719e+01 3.827678e+01
FPE(n) 1.403228e+16 1.413343e+16 1.444250e+16 1.545632e+16 1.599181e+16 1.583965e+16
                  7            8            9           10
AIC(n) 3.733798e+01 3.720314e+01 3.721887e+01 3.708865e+01
HQ(n)  3.778214e+01 3.769666e+01 3.776174e+01 3.768087e+01
SC(n)  3.845037e+01 3.843914e+01 3.857846e+01 3.857184e+01
FPE(n) 1.674832e+16 1.474327e+16 1.511360e+16 1.341617e+16
```

My big doubt is about the minimum selection. In this case i can go with a test and run with 1.L or 10.L, Probably 10 will be too much (idk)
But if i had to choose looking only to the values? What should i follow?